# 1 bloc emitting a List of states vs many blocs are emitting their own state

Tags: flutter, performance, optimization, bloc, state-management

Let's pretend we are drawing a chess table. We have a gameboard and 64 cells. We are smart enough to not build a whole board for a single move. I found 2 solutions for this situation.

1. Create a GameBoard bloc that emits a cell state list that had 64 cell states. And listen every cell's state with "context.select" inside a Builder widget.

```
class Example1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8;
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<GameBoardCubit>(
        create: (_) => GameBoardCubit(),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(
            8,
            (index1) => Row(
              children: List.generate(
                8,
                (index2) => Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    //Just for example
                    final state = context.select<GameBoardCubit, CellState>(
                        (value) => value.state[index1 * 8 + index2]);
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      height: size - 2,
                      width: size - 2,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class GameBoardCubit extends Cubit<List<CellState>> {
  GameBoardCubit() : super(List.generate(64, (index) => CellInitial()));

  void newState() => emit(List.generate(
      64, (index) => index % 2 == 0 ? CellNewState() : CellInitial()));
}

@immutable
abstract class CellState {}

class CellInitial extends CellState {}

class CellNewState extends CellState {}
```

2. Create 64 blocs and every Builder listens to its own bloc.

```
class Example2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final blocList = List.generate(64, (index) => CellCubit());
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: List.generate(
          8,
          (index1) => Row(
            children: List.generate(
              8,
              (index2) => BlocProvider.value(
                value: blocList[index1 * 8 + index2],
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    //Just for example
                    final state = context.watch<CellCubit>();
                    // Accessing bloc
                    // blocList[15].newState();
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      height: size - 2,
                      width: size - 2,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class CellCubit extends Cubit<CellState> {
  CellCubit() : super(CellInitial());
  int counter = 0;
  void newState() {
    emit(counter % 2 == 0 ? CellNewState() : CellInitial());
    counter++;
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class CellState {}

class CellInitial extends CellState {}

class CellNewState extends CellState {}
```

**Here is the question. Which way is more performant?**

You could say it doesn't matter you will not notice any difference between them. Let's say it will gonna make 10 moves in a second.

The first one emits 10 new List that has 64 CellState, every second. This means there is always gonna be created a new CellState for non-changed states too.

The second one has 64 blocs which means 64 different streams.

**Note:** newState() is only for example. We don't know how many cells' states will be changed every move. And it's **not** for a chess game. Just a **theoretical question**.